# 'Property not found' in subclass constructor

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, constructor

I have the next code:

GenericClass.h:

```
@interface GenericClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) char tile_inicial;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *color;
```

GenericClass.m

```
@implementation GenericClass

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}


- (id)initTodo:(char) tile
{
    _tile_inicial = tile;
    return self;
}

@end
```

Animals.h:

```
#import "GenericClass.h"

@interface Animals : GenericClass
    @property (nonatomic) bool fly;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *sound;
@end

@interface Cow : Animals
    @property (nonatomic) bool daLeche;
@end
```

Animals.m

```
#import "Animals.h"


@implementation Animals

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

- (id)initAnimal:(bool)fly :(NSString *) sound :(char) tile
{
    _fly = fly;
    _sound = sound;

    self = [super initTodo: tile];
    return self;
}
@end


@implementation Cow

-(id)init
{
    self = [super initAnimal: false :@"Muu Muu": 'v'];
    if (self) {
        _daLeche = true;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

The issue is I would like to call directly from the Cow constructor to any property (for example color or sound) and initialize it.
But if I try to do it without call the parent constructor it returns: "Property not found"
Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code you've put in your question doesn't look like it should compile, and you've not shown any code to suggest that these properties should exist.

Comment: Please post your actual code and not some made-up example. Where are the properties?

Comment: SubClass init calls something that doesn't exist and BaseClass tries to call a method that takes a parameter without passing one.  Other than that, anything could be happening.